# Kubernetes and PHP-FPM with multiple environments, problems with environment variables

Tags: php, laravel, docker, kubernetes, environment-variables

I'm having an issue right now when trying to create a PHP (Laravel) pod in my Kubernetes cluster. As php-fpm is a service run by the user www-data, he doesn't have access to the environments variables that Docker or Kubernetes sets up, which is the source of my problem.

We have beta and production pods, and previously, the only thing I did was setup an environment variable in my Kubernetes deployment which would tell the container if it had to use the beta or the prod configuration.

Sadly, since the php-fpm process can't access them, this is not possible. Is there a clean way to handle this? One way I can think of doing it right now is to put my two different .env files (config file for Laravel) in two different secrets in Kubernetes, then after that have a script as my Docker image's entrypoint that copies the right .env at the root of the project since the script will have access to the ENV variables.

If someone has a cleaner way in mind, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the solution I proposed in my original post, thanks for trying to help! It works fine, I was just looking for something a bit cleaner!

Answer (score 1):

You could put the `clear_env = no` in your php-fpm.conf or a file included from it, [as discussed here](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/74#issuecomment-79102385).

Comment: Yes yes I did it, but if I'm not mistaken this doesn't change the fact that docker and Kubernetes ENV variables are set on the root user's context right? Other users like www-data wouldn't have access to them anyways no?